# sailsjs jwt token based authentication example

Tags: node.js, sails.js, passport.js, jwt, passport-local

I am following [this Tutorial](https://ericswann.wordpress.com/2015/04/24/nozus-js-1-intro-to-sails-with-passport-and-jwt-json-web-token-auth/).

But when i do `sails lift` to run my application, i am getting below error.

> throw new TypeError('JwtStrategy requires a function to retrieve jwt from requests (see option jwtFromRequest)');
>           ^
>
> TypeError: JwtStrategy requires a function to retrieve jwt from requests (see option jwtFromRequest)

Please help me how to solve this error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is in the configuration of the options for the JwtStrategy, according to the [github](https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt) page, it's missing one option, jwtFromRequest, you need to use an extractor provided with the passport-jwt.

These are my modifications:

```
var ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
var JWT_STRATEGY_CONFIG = {
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader(),
  secretOrKey: SECRET,
  issuer : ISSUER,
  audience: AUDIENCE,
  passReqToCallback: false
};
```

I hope it help you